# Регулярное выражение для замены тэга в файле

Tags: php, регулярные-выражения, xml

Необходимо заменить слово %random% на свое в тэгах при помощи PHP. Слово генерируется рандомно и может иметь любое кол-во символов.

```
 <?xml version = "1.0" encoding="UTF-8" standalone="yes"?>
    <VFPData>
        <%random%>
            <buy>Success</buy>
        </%random%>
    </VFPData>
```

**Пример текста:**

```
<VFPData>
            <_fdrRE2gfg>
                <buy>Success</buy>
            </_fdrRE2gfg>
<_fdrRE2gfg>
                <buy>Success</buy>
            </_fdrRE2gfg>

        </VFPData>
```

> PS Это XML документ. Кол-во элементов массива не ограничено.

Заранее благодарен.

Comment: пробовали с функцией `str_replace` ?

Comment: Лучше пример текста приведите с несколькими такими словами и укажите на что хоть можно ориентироваться, если слово заранее не известно

Answer (score 0):

Самый банальный вариант такой:

```
$nexXml = preg_replace("#(</?)(" . preg_quote($find) . ")>#", "$1" . htmlentities($repl) . ">", $oldXml);
```